# Override (refresh) echo statement instead of adding it along with an old one

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I've created an input that allows user to update info about him/her. Input shows entered info immediately beyond it (I use AJAX). I maid everything work, the problem is that when a user decides to change personal info, enters some data and hits 'save' - it does not *override* or *refresh* the previous data shown but puts it *underneath it*.

My point is to allow user to immediately change info about him/her and display it right away and not to display new record along with old one.

Here's my index.php

```
<head>   
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$(".submit_button").click(function() {
var textcontent = $("#content").val();
var dataString = 'content='+ textcontent;
if(textcontent=='')
{
alert("Enter some text..");
$("#content").focus();
}
else
{
$("#flash").show();
$("#flash").fadeIn(400).html('<span class="load">Loading..</span>');
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "action.php",
data: dataString,
cache: true,
success: function(html){
$("#show").after(html);
document.getElementById('content').value='';
$("#flash").hide();
$("#content").focus();
}  
});
}
return false;
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>


<div class="container">

<div class="main">
<form  method="post" name="form" action="">
<textarea style="width:500px; font-size:14px; height:60px; font-weight:bold;   resize:none;" name="content" id="content" ></textarea><br />
<input type="submit" id="submit"value="Post" name="submit" class="submit_button"/>
</form>
</div>
<div class="space"></div>
<div id="flash" align="left"  ></div>
<div id="show" align="left"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

action.php

```
<?php
include('db.php');
$check = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM user order by age desc");
if(isset($_POST['content']))
{
$content=$_POST['content'];
$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];


$query = "UPDATE user SET rain = '$content' WHERE name = 'gala'";
mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die("error querying record");
$fetch= mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT rain FROM user WHERE name = 'gala' LIMIT    1");
$result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fetch);
}
?>
```

And here is where my input goes - here is the problem. It adds the new record while I want it to get refreshed!

```
<div class="showbox"> <?php echo $result['rain'];  ?> </div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please take care about sql injection and don't use user input directly in sql statements (for more information see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

In your ajax success callback you use jQuerys `.after()` function. After appends the given html (your div class "showbox") to the div with id "box". So everytime you hit save, another div.showbox will be added to DOM.

Use jQuerys `.html()` instead to replace already present content

Replace

```
$("#show").after(html);
```

with

```
$("#show").html(html);
```